# Помогите разобраться с поведением фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-manager, fragmentpageradapter

Пишу приложение, где будет масса фрагментов и хочу чтоб они не умирали. Чтоб можно было вернуться назад и не загружать данные с api снова.

Существует фрагмент `MyProfile`, из него можно перейти во фрагмент на `Friends`(список друзей). От туда на `SomeoneProfile`, ну и соответственно тоже в друзья этого пользователя.

`Friends` содержит `PagerAdapter` с фрагментами `AllFriends` и `OnLineFriends`.
Все это прекрасно работает пока я использую `replace` для моего главного контейнера.

Но когда я добавляю `add` вместо `replace`, фрагмент `Friends` перестает работать корректно. Во-первых он вообще вылетает из стека (при нажатии назад его как будто и не было ). Затем при повторном его открытии `PagerAdapter`не отображает свои фрагменты, хотя они существуют, загружают данные и пытаются обновить свои `Recycler'ы`, но `bind` не происходит.

Для `PagerAdapter` кстати используется `SupportFragmentManager`, а для замены и добавления фрагментов я использую `FragmentManager`.
Заменил все фрагменты на `support.v4`, теперь при нажатии назад `Friends` не выпадает из стека но так же не отображает свои фрагменты.

Подскажите, куда копать и что попробовать сделать чтоб исправить.
Какие вообще лучше использовать способы для реализации такого функционала(чтоб фрагменты не умирали, оставались в том же состоянии и со своими данными)? Поделитесь пожалуйста примерами, если где-то есть.

Фрагмент `Friends`

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.myFriendsViewPager)
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @BindView(R.id.myFriendsTabLayout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_friends, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MyFriendsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFriendsPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, tabLayout );
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Код замены фрагмента

```
 FriendsFragment myFriendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();  
 FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();  
 transaction.add(R.id.main_act_fragment_container, myFriendsFragment);  
 transaction.addToBackStack(null); transaction.commit();
```

Comment: покуажите пожлста метод с помощью которого вы выполняете смену всех фграментов. Плюс, покажите фрагмент Friends (тот что не отображает начинку после клика на back)

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: вам не нужно добиваться того, чтобы фрагменты не уничтожались. Даже если наставить костылей на обход поворота устройства, это все равно может произойти, если приложение, к примеру, свернуть в фон. вам нужно сохранять их текщее состояние и востанавливать его при потере данных фрагментами - именно так работают приложения на андроид, а не хранят все текущее состояние приложения в оперативной памяти, она не резиновая и вообще система в любой момент может освободить ее часть, если она ей понадобится, уничтожив ваш песочный замок.

Comment: чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, в первую очередь нужно знать, что у вас за данные. как и где хранятся, как выводятся на экран и тд.

Comment: Мне кажется если все восстанавливать от куда то, то будут тормоза. Вот например взять инстаграм, там можно много переходов сделать и состояние сохраняется при том много image view во фрагменте. Неужели все сохраняется во всяком переходе? Ну а так вообще предположительно пользователь не будет открывать 50 фрагментов последовательно. То что я пишу можно рассматривать на примере инстаграма

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста какие механизмы использовать для сохранения состояния? AsyncTaskLoader'ы например?

Comment: все зависит от отображаемых данных  и способа их хранения, о чем в вашем вопросе ни слова. Тормозов никаких не будет при правильной реализации

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что проблема в том, что View фрагмента еще не уничтожена, а значит `onViewCreated` не отработает. Дле эксперимент, предлагаю вам перенести инициализацию адаптера в onStart.

Comment: это только теоретическое предположение. если это окажется так, то над решение подумаем еще.

Comment: Дело в том что она отрабатывает и фрагменты pager'а создаются но не отображаются